# How to assign a value to a TensorFlow variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign a new value to a tensorflow variable in python.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.Variable(0)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)

print(x.eval())

x.assign(1)
print(x.eval())
```

But the output I get is

```
0
0
```

So the value has not changed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

In TF1, the statement [`x.assign(1)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Variable#assign) does not actually assign the value `1` to `x`, but rather creates a [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) that you have to explicitly *run* to update the variable.* A call to [`Operation.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#run) or [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session#run) can be used to run the operation:

```
assign_op = x.assign(1)
sess.run(assign_op)  # or `assign_op.op.run()`
print(x.eval())
# ==> 1
```

(* In fact, it returns a `tf.Tensor`, corresponding to the updated value of the variable, to make it easier to chain assignments.)

However, in TF2 [`x.assign(1)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) will now assign the value eagerly:

```
x.assign(1)
print(x.numpy())
# ==> 1
```

Comment: Thanks!

assign_op.run()  gives an error:AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'run'. 

But sess.run(assign_op) runs perfectly fine.

Comment: In this example, is the data that the `Variable` `x` stored in memory before the `assign` operation / mutable tensor was run overwritten or is a new tensor created that stores the updated value?

Comment: The current implementation of `assign()` overwrites the existing value.

Comment: Is there a way to assign a new value to a `Variable` without creating any additional operations in the graph? It seems that each variable has an Assign operation created for it already, but calling `my_var.assign()` or `tf.assign()` creates a new operation instead of using the existing one.

Comment: I don't think if this is relevant here, but you can give to `assign` a tensor parameter such as math operation. And in this way create a counter which is updated every time the assign operation is evaluated: `op = t.assign(tf.add(t, 1))`.

Answer (score 43):

You can also assign a new value to a `tf.Variable` without adding an operation to the graph: [`tf.Variable.load(value, session)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load). This function can also save you adding placeholders when assigning a value from outside the graph and it is useful in case the graph is finalized.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(x))  # Prints 0.
x.load(1, sess)
print(sess.run(x))  # Prints 1.
```

Update: This is depricated in TF2 as eager execution is default and graphs are [no longer exposed in the user-facing API](https://medium.com/tensorflow/effective-tensorflow-2-0-best-practices-and-whats-changed-a0ca48767aff).

Comment: Caveat: you can't load it with array having different shape than the shape of initial value of the variable!

Comment: Variable.load (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Prefer Variable.assign which has equivalent behavior in 2.X.

Not sure how to change the values of a variable in Tensorflow 2.0 without adding an op to the graph

Answer (score 15):

First of all you can assign values to variables/constants just by feeding values into them the same way you do it with placeholders. So this is perfectly legal to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(x, feed_dict={x: 3})
```

Regarding your confusion with the [tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) operator. In TF nothing is executed before you run it inside of the session. So you always have to do something like this: `op_name = tf.some_function_that_create_op(params)` and then inside of the session you run `sess.run(op_name)`. Using assign as an example you will do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0)
y = tf.assign(x, 1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(x)
    print sess.run(y)
    print sess.run(x)
```

Comment: @RobinDinse, it does. In the above example, you get 0,1,1 as your stdout.

Comment: Note that feeding the value via the `feed_dict` does not permanently assign that value to the variable, but only for that particular run call.

Comment: @RobinDinse how can I assign that value permanently? If you can, see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141762/tensorflow-how-to-assign-an-updated-numpy?noredirect=1#comment93177616_53141762

Answer (score 4):

Also, it has to be noted that if you're using `your_tensor.assign()`, then the `tf.global_variables_initializer` need not be called explicitly since the assign operation does it for you in the background.

Example:

```
In [212]: w = tf.Variable(12)
In [213]: w_new = w.assign(34)

In [214]: with tf.Session() as sess:
     ...:     sess.run(w_new)
     ...:     print(w_new.eval())

# output
34
```

However, this will not initialize all variables, but it will only initialize the variable on which `assign` was executed on.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544044/6721863).  I looked in a lot of places that always created the same problem.  Basically, I did not want to assign a value to the weights, but simply change the weights.  The short version of the above answer is:

`tf.keras.backend.set_value(tf_var, numpy_weights)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

w= tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32) #good practice to set the type of the variable
cost = 10 + 5*w + w*w
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session = tf.Session()
session.run(init)

print(session.run(w))

session.run(train)
print(session.run(w)) # runs one step of gradient descent

for i in range(10000):
  session.run(train)

print(session.run(w))
```

Note the output will be:

```
0.0
-0.049999997
-2.499994
```

This means at the very start the Variable was 0, as defined, then after just one step of gradient decent the variable was -0.049999997, and after 10.000 more steps we are reaching -2.499994 (based on our cost function).

Note: You originally used the Interactive session. Interactive session is useful when multiple different sessions needed to be run in the same script. However, I used the non interactive session for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tensorflow eager execution mode which is latest.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
my_int_variable = tf.get_variable("my_int_variable", [1, 2, 3])
print(my_int_variable)
```

Answer (score -10):

There is an easier approach:

```
x = tf.Variable(0)
x = x + 1
print x.eval()
```

Comment: the o.p. was examining the usage of `tf.assign`, not addition.