# Tensorflow: How to modify the value in tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Since I need to write some preprocesses for the data before using Tensorflow to train models, some modifications on the `tensor` is needed. However, I have no idea about how to modify the values in `tensor` like the way using `numpy`.

The best way of doing so is that it is able to modify `tensor` directly. Yet, it seems not possible in the current version of Tensorflow. An alternative way is changing `tensor` to `ndarray` for the process, and then use `tf.convert_to_tensor` to change back.

The key is how to change `tensor` to `ndarray`.
1) `tf.contrib.util.make_ndarray(tensor)`:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/contrib.util.html#make_ndarray
It seems the easiest way as per the document, yet I cannot find this function in the current version of the Tensorflow. Second, the input of it is `TensorProto` rather than `tensor`.
2) Use `a.eval()` to copy `a` to another `ndarray`
Yet, it works only at using `tf.InteractiveSession()` in notebook.

A simple case with codes shows below. The purpose of this code is making that the `tfc` has the same output as `npc` after the process.

**HINT**
You should treat that `tfc` and `npc` are independent to each other. This meets the situation that at first the retrieved training data is in `tensor` format with [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder).

---

**Source code**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

tfc = tf.constant([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])
npc = np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])
row = np.array([[.1,.2]])
print('tfc:\n', tfc.eval())
print('npc:\n', npc)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        npc[i,j] += row[0,j]

print('modified tfc:\n', tfc.eval())
print('modified npc:\n', npc)
```

---

**Output:**

tfc:
 [[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
npc:
 [[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
modified tfc:
 [[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
modified npc:
 [[ 1.1  2.2]
 [ 3.1  4.2]]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use assign and eval (or sess.run) the assign:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

npc = np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])
tfc = tf.Variable(npc) # Use variable 

row = np.array([[.1,.2]])

with tf.Session() as sess:   
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run() # need to initialize all variables

    print('tfc:\n', tfc.eval())
    print('npc:\n', npc)
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            npc[i,j] += row[0,j]
    tfc.assign(npc).eval() # assign_sub/assign_add is also available.
    print('modified tfc:\n', tfc.eval())
    print('modified npc:\n', npc)
```

It outputs:

```
tfc:
 [[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
npc:
 [[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
modified tfc:
 [[ 1.1  2.2]
 [ 3.1  4.2]]
modified npc:
 [[ 1.1  2.2]
 [ 3.1  4.2]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your thought is supposing that `tfc` shares the same value as `npc` at the beginning so that you can first process on `npc` and then `assign` it to `tfc` for the same output. This is however not the case.   
In the practical case that the only data you have is `tfc`, suggesting you need to treat the `npc` does not exist at the beginning. So the key should be at how to process the data in `tfc`.

Comment: @user3030046 Depends on the operations. If they are simple add/sub, use assign_sub/assign_add. Others, we have many other ways. Do you want to update elements in a tf.Tensor? If you give me a use case, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: My case is that I am trying to implement the CBOW (the last cell in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e39d8feebb9666a331345cd8d960f5ade4652bba/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb). And it needs to sum over the vectors of all nearby skips for prediction. Specifically, it is like using a row-wise sum over a 10-by-3 matrix and outputs a 10-by-1 vector. This convolutional operation will repeat on a 10-by-100 matrix and it will yield an output matrix of the identical size. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user3030046 Could you add another question with some sample code? It would be better to understand your question and answer it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while.  The answer given will add `assign` operations to the graph (and thus needlessly increase the size of the `.meta` if you subsequently save a checkpoint).  A better solution is to use `tf.keras.backend.set_value`.  One could emulate that with raw tensorflow by doing:

```
    for x, value in zip(tf.global_variables(), values_npfmt):
      if hasattr(x, '_assign_placeholder'):
        assign_placeholder = x._assign_placeholder
        assign_op = x._assign_op
      else:
        assign_placeholder = array_ops.placeholder(tf_dtype, shape=value.shape)
        assign_op = x.assign(assign_placeholder)
        x._assign_placeholder = assign_placeholder
        x._assign_op = assign_op
      get_session().run(assign_op, feed_dict={assign_placeholder: value})
```