# Numpy Indexing Operations with Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to update the values of a tensor like:

```
ldream[w,:,x,y,z] = 0
```

But keep getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by creating a boolean mask using a numpy array:

```
ldream_mask = np.zeros(ldream.shape, dtype=np.bool)
```

Then selecting the desired indices and marking them as True

```
ldream_mask[w,:,x,y,z] =  True
```

Then using tf.where to update the desired indices using ldream_mask

Answer (score 0):

It seems `ldream` is a tensorflow variable, which unfortunately cannot be directly assigned values the same way as numpy arrays.

To update the value of a tensor in tensorflow, you can make an assignment operation and then run (eval) that operation.  Here is an example on how to do this:

[Tensorflow: How to modify the value in tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071788/tensorflow-how-to-modify-the-value-in-tensor)

The reason for this is that when you code your tf variables and operations, you are actually "staging" them to happen at a later time (such as when you do `sess.run`); like a blueprint of how tensorflow will actually run.

Comment: If all you do is just linking another answer, then you should close this one as a duplicate

Comment: @facultyofmusic that answer refers to modifying a tf.Variable, I want to select values in a Tensor based by using indices and slices like with numpy arrays e.g ldream = [x,:,y,a,b]