# Assign value to Variable in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to assign zero to Tensorflow variable as seen below. Is it possible to do that? What should I do?

```
layer = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, h), b))
layer[0] = 0
```

In the example above, I want to set zero value to the first index of the variable calculated by multiplying x matrix and h vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign it directly but you can use `.assign()` operation to make it happen, [here is the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html). Also after you assign you have to run the operation using `.run()` or `.eval()`. In my opinion, this code should work:

```
layerOp = layer[0].assign(0)
sess.run(layerOp)
```

Please find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable) for reference.

Comment: Just to clarify: `layer` in the above is a `tf.Tensor` rather than a `tf.Variable`, so the `assign()` method isn't defined on it. The easiest way to achieve the desired outcome is using `tf.slice()` and `tf.concat()` to build the desired result.