# How to assign a value from a file to a TensorFlow variable without storing 2 copies in memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34220532/395857) one can use the statement [`x.assign(1)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign) followed by a call to [`Operation.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Operation.run) or [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) to assign the value `1` to the TensorFlow variable `x`.

However, this solution stores `1` twice in the memory. This can be an issue when the value to assign is large (e.g., word embeddings).

How to assign a value from a file to a TensorFlow variable without storing 2 copies of the value in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid storing the value in Python memory by using TensorFlow readers. IE, something like

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer("myfile")
x.assign(reader.read(filename_queue))
```

You want to assign something than string you may have to have to combine `reader.read` with an op that produces the desired type, ie, `TextLineReader` + `tf.decode_csv`

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data