# How to assign values in a TensorFlow while_loop

Tags: python, filter, tensorflow, while-loop, time-series

The goal is to implement a recurrent function in TensorFlow to filter a signal over time.

The `input` is later presented as a 5-D tensor of form `[batch, in_depth, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`. I want to use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) to iterate over `in_depth` and reassign values depended on values of previous time steps. However, I fail to reassign variable values within the loop.

In order to simplify the problem, I have create a 1-D version of the problem:

```
def condition(i, signal):
    return tf.less(i, signal.shape[0])

def operation(i, signal):
    signal = tf.get_variable("signal")
    signal = signal[i].assign(signal[i-1]*2)
    i = tf.add(i, 1)
    return (i, signal)

with tf.variable_scope("scope"):
    i = tf.constant(1)
    init = tf.constant_initializer(0)
    signal = tf.get_variable("scope", [4], tf.float32, init, trainable = False)
    signal = tf.assign(signal[0], 1.2)

with tf.variable_scope("scope", reuse = True):
    loops_vars = [i, signal]
    i, signal = tf.while_loop(condition, operation, loop_vars, back_prop = False)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    i, signal = session.run([i, signal])
```

[`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) returns an operation, which has to be run in a session in order to be evaluated ([see here for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable)).

I expected, that TensorFlow would chain the operations within the loop and hence execute the assignments once I run a session and request `signal`. However, when I execute the given code and print the result, `signal` contatins `[1.2, 0, 0, 0]` and `i` contains (as expected) `4`.

What is my misconception here and how can I change the code such that the values of `signal` are reassigned?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're creating new copies of `signal`. Have a look at [How Does Variable Scope Work?](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope) and check `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse`, also, you easily skip passing `signal` to all your while loop functions, since you have access to `signal` everywhere.

Comment: @NULL No, no copies are created. The variable scope is set to be reused before creating the while_loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loop variables are only updated through the returned values of the body function, you should not use your own assignment operations. Instead, you need to return the value that you want `signal` to have after the loop, as with `i`.

Also, you shouldn't use `tf.get_variable` in the body or the condition, just use the parameters that you receive.

```
# ...
def operation(i, signal):
    shape = signal.shape
    signal = tf.concat([signal[:i], [signal[i - 1] * 2], signal[i + 1:]], axis=0)
    signal.set_shape(shape) # Shapes have to be invariant for the loop
    i = tf.add(i, 1)
    return (i, signal)

with tf.variable_scope("scope"):
    i = tf.constant(1)
    init = tf.constant_initializer(1.2) # init signal here and avoid tf.assign
    signal = tf.get_variable("scope", [4], tf.float32, init, trainable = False)
    # signal = tf.assign(signal[0], 1.2) 

# ...
```