# How to properly update variables in a while loop in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, while-loop

Can someone please explain (or point me to the relevant place in the documentation that I've missed) how to properly update a `tf.Variable()` in a `tf.while_loop`? I am trying to update variables in the loop that will store some information until the next iteration of the loop using the `assign()` method. However, this isn't doing anything.

As the values of `mu_tf` and `sigma_tf` are being updated by the minimizer, while `step_mu` isn't, I am obviously doing something wrong, but I don't understand what it is. Specifically, I guess I should say that I know [`assign()` does not do anything until it is executed when the graph is run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220750/8931942), so I know that I can do

`sess.run(step_mu.assign(mu_tf))`

and that will update `step_mu`, but I want to do this in the loop correctly. I don't understand how to add an `assign` operation to the body of the loop.

A simplified working example of what I'm doing follows here:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

mu_true = 0.5
sigma_true = 1.5

n_events = 100000

# Placeholders
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

# Variables
mu_tf = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_normal(shape=[], mean=0., stddev=0.1,
                                                dtype=tf.float32),
                    dtype=tf.float32)
sigma_tf = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.abs(tf.random_normal(shape=[], mean=1., stddev=0.1,
                                                dtype=tf.float32)),
                       dtype=tf.float32,
                       constraint=lambda x: tf.abs(x))

step_mu = tf.Variable(initial_value=-99999., dtype=tf.float32)   
step_loss = tf.Variable(initial_value=-99999., dtype=tf.float32)

# loss function
gaussian_dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu_tf, scale=sigma_tf)
log_prob = gaussian_dist.log_prob(value=X)
negative_log_likelihood = -1.0 * tf.reduce_sum(log_prob)

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

# sample data
x_sample = np.random.normal(loc=mu_true, scale=sigma_true, size=n_events)

# Construct the while loop.
def cond(step):
    return tf.less(step, 10)

def body(step):
    # gradient step
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=negative_log_likelihood)

    # update step parameters
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
        step_mu.assign(mu_tf)

        return tf.add(step,1)

loop = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [tf.constant(0)])

# Execute the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    step_loss = sess.run(fetches=negative_log_likelihood, feed_dict={X: x_sample})

    print('Before loop:\n')
    print('mu_tf: {}'.format(sess.run(mu_tf)))
    print('sigma_tf: {}'.format(sess.run(sigma_tf)))
    print('step_mu: {}'.format(sess.run(step_mu)))
    print('step_loss: {}\n'.format(step_loss))

    sess.run(fetches=loop, feed_dict={X: x_sample})

    print('After loop:\n')
    print('mu_tf: {}'.format(sess.run(mu_tf)))
    print('sigma_tf: {}'.format(sess.run(sigma_tf)))
    print('step_mu: {}'.format(sess.run(step_mu)))
    print('step_loss: {}'.format(step_loss))
```

Comment: You'll want to have your assigns and adds as control inputs (argument to tf.control_dependencies) and train_op in the body. See <https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies>

Comment: @RobR, can you elaborate? I had tried that (what I think you're referring to) earlier, and it didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Your structure seems unusual. Generally the train_op is called in a python for loop rather than embedded in a tf.while_loop. Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: @RobR, perhaps misguidedly the example I am showing is not actually at all what I am trying to do --- it is just much simpler and incomplete. I am trying to take a MLE fit algorithm that I have and then implement it efficiently in the graph before running it. So the `tf.while_loop` is to replace a `while True:` loop that would break once parameter or loss convergence has occurred. I thought it would just be easier to put in the simple "less than 10" condition. Though it seems that this has just been confusing, sorry.

Would it be clearer if I posted what I'm actually trying to do?

Comment: Has this been figured out? I am also stuck with the same issue

Comment: @AseemHegshetye can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? In addition to @RobR's advice my colleagues who are more skilled then I just shrugged and suggested putting the train op (`sess.run(train_op, {X: x_sample})`) in a loop as that's what they do. I haven't followed up on this in some time, but it would be interesting to see what you're trying to do as well.