# Getting weights from tensorflow.js neural network

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have this sequential model:

```js
this.model = tf.sequential()

this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 16, useBias : true, inputDim : 7})) // input
this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 16, useBias : true, activation: 'sigmoid'})) // hidden
this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 3, useBias : true, activation: 'sigmoid'})) // hidden 2
```

I checked API for tensorflow.js, but there's nothing about getting weights(kernels) of neural network. So, how can I get weights and then change them, to apply new weights?(for unsupervised learning)

Comment: Your not manually trying to update the weights are you?

Comment: @Daniel i want to do it, but don't know how

Comment: If you are manually applying weights to find the optimal weight, you shouldn't need to. Just train the network and it will find the optimal weights.

Comment: @Daniel i want to use genetic algorithm, therefore i need to change weights for crossover and mutations

Comment: Oh ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable Does this help? What you're doing will be very messy in TF. It'd be easier in torch.

Comment: @Daniel pytorch would be good, but Im using javascript(tensorflow.js), anyway it doesn't matter, cause I found neataptic.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is probably a simpler and cleaner way to do what you want, but regardless:

Calling `this.model.getWeights()` will give you an array of Variables that correspond to layer weights and biases. Calling `data()` on any of these array elements will return a promise that you can resolve to get the weights.

I haven't tried manually setting the weights, but there is a `this.model.setWeights()` method.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to print off all the weights:

```
for (let i = 0; i < model.getWeights().length; i++) {
    console.log(model.getWeights()[i].dataSync());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the weights (kernel and bias) of the first dense layer:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4, inputShape: [8]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4}));
model.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });

// kernel:
model.layers[0].getWeights()[0].print()

// bias:
model.layers[0].getWeights()[1].print()
```

Comment: What exactly the kernel prints?