# Are the weights of a pre-trained Tensorflow model that has been ported to TensorFlow.js accessible at runtime through the model object?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

How do I access the weights of a model during debug?

When I inspect `model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0]` during execution in the debugger the actual weights aren't present. However when I `console.log` the expression the weights are printed. It seems like there is some sort of deferred execution going on?

I have created a snippet below that is based on the toxic classifier [medium article](https://medium.com/tensorflow/text-classification-using-tensorflow-js-an-example-of-detecting-offensive-language-in-browser-e2b94e3565ce) that shows how to access the weights object for a specific layer.

```js
const threshold = 0.9;

// Which toxicity labels to return.
const labelsToInclude = ['identity_attack', 'insult', 'threat'];

toxicity.load(threshold, labelsToInclude).then(model => {
    // Now you can use the `model` object to label sentences. 
    model.classify(['you suck']).then(predictions => {
    console.log("Specific weights: "+ model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0])
      document.getElementById("predictions").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(predictions, null, 2);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Activity 1: Basic HTML Bio</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/toxicity"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="predictions">
Will be populated by prebuilt toxicity model
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091466/getting-weights-from-tensorflow-js-neural-network) I was able to derive how to access the weights.

For each layer there is a `data` promise will give access to the weights.

```js
const threshold = 0.9;

// Which toxicity labels to return.
const labelsToInclude = ['identity_attack', 'insult', 'threat'];

toxicity.load(threshold, labelsToInclude).then(model => {
    // Now you can use the `model` object to label sentences. 
    model.classify(['you suck']).then(predictions => {
      model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0].data().then(
        function(value) {
        document.getElementById("specific_weights").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(value);
        });
      
      document.getElementById("predictions").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(predictions, null, 2);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Activity 1: Basic HTML Bio</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/toxicity"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="predictions">
Will be populated by prebuilt toxicity model
</div>
<div id="specific_weights">
Will contain weights for specific layer
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each layer in an array of tensors. The weights of the layer can be accessed by iterating over the array.

```
const t = model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0] // t is a tensor
t.print() // will display the tensor in the console
// to add value to the weight
t.add(tf.scalar(0.5))
```

console.log(model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0]) will display an object and not the value of the tensor. The reason being that a tensor is a class in TypeScript which is transpiled in js as an object of type `Function`. That is the reason why `console.log(model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0])` will print an object with keys being the attributes of the class tensor. One needs to invoke the `print` method to see the underlying values of the tensor

```js
const threshold = 0.9;

// Which toxicity labels to return.
const labelsToInclude = ['identity_attack', 'insult', 'threat'];

toxicity.load(threshold, labelsToInclude).then(model => {
    // print weights
    model.model.weights['dense_3/bias'][0].print()
    // continue processing
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Activity 1: Basic HTML Bio</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/toxicity"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to get the tensor value on `cpu` and display it using `innerHTML` of the dom element, you can consider using [data](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.data) or [dataSync](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.data)

Comment: so hypothetically if I wanted to add .5 to all the weights in a particular layer in code. is that possible? if so how?

Comment: @lapolonio, you can add value to the weights by using tensor operators like `add`. See the edited answer