# tensorflow: how to assign an updated numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow, assign, tensor

I'm new in tensorflow and I'm trying to understand its behaviors; I'm trying to define all the operations outside the session scope so to optimize the computation time.
In the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np  
Z_tensor = tf.Variable(np.float32( np.zeros((1, 10)) ), name="Z_tensor")
Z_np = np.zeros((1,10))
update_Z = tf.assign(Z_tensor, Z_np)

Z_np[0][2:4] = 4

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(Z_tensor.initializer)
    print(Z_tensor.eval())
    print(update_Z.eval(session=sess))
```

I obtain as ouput:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Instead I expected as output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 0. 4. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

It seems that the `Z_np` array is not updated in the assign operation and I don't understand why.
Doesn't the operation

```
  update_Z = tf.assign(Z_tensor, Z_np)
```

make a link with `Z_np`?

Comment: Can't you just move `Z_np[0][2:4] = 4` above `update_Z = tf.assign(Z_tensor, Z_np)`? My guess is that because the indexing of `Z_np` is not evaluated by the graph it isn't being updated.

Comment: not evaluated by the graph??
the graph would have just a reference to Z_np... or not??

Comment: however, the result seems to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use tf.assign, it expects a tensor as the second argument.  Because you provided a Numpy array, it automatically promotes it to a CONSTANT tensor and places it in the graph at that moment.  Because of this, no changes you make to the Numpy array will have any effect on the TensorFlow graph.  In order to get the desired functionality, you should use a placeholder:

```
Z_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, Z_np.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(Z_tensor.initializer)
    print(Z_tensor.eval(feed_dict={Z_placeholder: Z_np}, session=sess))
    Z_np[0][2:4] = 4
    print(Z_tensor.eval(feed_dict={Z_placeholder: Z_np}, session=sess))
```

Comment: In my case, this code doesn't work and raises the error `eval() got an unexpected keyword argument 'feed_dict'`. However a similar code works where, instead of eval, I use `update_Z = tf.assign(tensor_Z, Z_placeholder)`, then in the `with`: `sess.run(update_Z,feed_dict={Z_placeholder: Z_np})`. Do you know why ?