# Tensorflow1.15: Modify checkpoint variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently try to modify variables in a checkpoint/meta file from a ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco model.

In my following code I try to multiply one trainable variables and then save all variables back to a new checkpoint file.

While the code is running the modification seem to work. But when I load the checkpoint again for another run it always starts with the initial values.

```
model_dir = os.path.join("TrainData", "graphmod", "model.ckpt-5081")
out =  os.path.join("TrainData", "graphmod", "modi_model.ckpt")

sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()

# Read Checkpoint
if os.path.exists(out+".meta"):
    print("Load Modded Checkpoint")
    graph = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(out+".meta")   
else:
    print("Load new Checkpoint")
    graph = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(model_dir+".meta") 


with sess.as_default():

    # Get Values
    tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer().run()
    var = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
    v = var[1]
    data = v.value().eval(session=sess)
    print(data) #Print1

    # Modify value
    ndata = data * 2
    print(ndata) #Print2
   
    #Update value
    assign_op = tf.compat.v1.assign(v, ndata)
    sess.run(assign_op)

    test =  tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
    print(test[1].value().eval()) #Print3

    # Save checkpoint with modifed variables
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    saved_path = saver.save(sess, out)
```

Console:

Print1

> [0.69119406 1.0427513  0.7505     0.9178902  2.0594552  0.9987083
> 0.43727568 0.8661325  0.47436237 0.3026007  1.668194   2.143268
> 2.365045   2.0043123  0.44265845 0.40587783 0.55946845 0.34303743
> 1.4615791  1.1735393  0.51035655 1.7895113  0.5164299  0.99509645
> 1.5685631  0.91277903 1.2804638  1.6940569  0.76734847 0.9846769
> 0.18623662 1.2584378 ]

Print2

> [1.3823881  2.0855026  1.501      1.8357804  4.1189103  1.9974166
> 0.87455136 1.732265   0.94872475 0.6052014  3.336388   4.286536
> 4.73009    4.0086246  0.8853169  0.81175566 1.1189369  0.68607485
> 2.9231582  2.3470786  1.0207131  3.5790226  1.0328598  1.9901929
> 3.1371262  1.8255581  2.5609276  3.3881137  1.5346969  1.9693538
> 0.37247324 2.5168755 ]

Print3

> [1.3823881  2.0855026  1.501      1.8357804  4.1189103  1.9974166
> 0.87455136 1.732265   0.94872475 0.6052014  3.336388   4.286536
> 4.73009    4.0086246  0.8853169  0.81175566 1.1189369  0.68607485
> 2.9231582  2.3470786  1.0207131  3.5790226  1.0328598  1.9901929
> 3.1371262  1.8255581  2.5609276  3.3881137  1.5346969  1.9693538
> 0.37247324 2.5168755 ]

I tried to just save the trainable variables. The new checkpoint contained the variables i wanted to save but still with the old values. So i guess my problem lays somewhere in the part where i try to update the existing varibales with the new value.

I also tried the solutions from [How to assign a value to a TensorFlow variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable) but it does not work for me.

- **Tensorflow Version: 1.15**
- **Python 3.7.7**
- **Numpy: 1.17.4**